# Gray scale to text scan image to black/white image with higher resolution

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

```
convert 0101.jp2 -threshold 50% -type bilevel  -monochrome -compress LZW ../0101.tiff
```

The resulting image looks jagged when I use the above command to convert a colored scanned text page to a black/white image (must be one bit per pixel). I want to make it of a higher resolution to look smoother. How can I use convert to do so?

Note that SO automatically converts tif image to jpg format so the output image shown below is not the same as the output image. You will need to run the convert command to get the true output image in tif.

[image]
[image]

Comment: once you make the image binary, you will get aliasing (stair-steps) on the text. The only way to make it smoother is to blur it some and then apply -level 50x100% (or possibly 0x50%, don't recall which offhand depending upon polarity of bw image). But that may not look good due to the narrow text characters.  If you have PDF input, you can use -density to create a larger image and then resize down to normal to get higher quality. But that only works for vector formats

Comment: I want a solution working for this type of bitmap images. Vector images are not the concern in this question.

Answer (score 1):

If instead of thresholding you apply a strong contrast the gray pixels on the edge remain in a range of grays and the output is not jagged.

```
convert Original.jpg -sigmoidal-contrast 30 Corrected.jpg
```

[image]

(there are several ways to increase contrast in Magick)

Comment: I want the output to be one bit per pixel using lossless compression. This does not do so.